# How to get back to GameScene after appearing a Gameover scene?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift4, skscene

I have a problem with the `Gamescene`. after the game is over a gameover scene will appear that allows me to click on NewGame Button but the thing is when I click on it the `Gamescene` will appear again a way bigger.

```
import UIKit
import SpriteKit

class GameOver: SKScene{

    var score: Int = 0

    //var scoreLabel: SKLabelNode!
    var newGameButtonNode: SKSpriteNode!

    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

        newGameButtonNode = (self.childNode(withName: "NewGameButton") as! SKSpriteNode)
        newGameButtonNode.texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "NewGame")
    }

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        let touch = touches.first
        if let locations = touch?.location(in: self){
            let node = self.nodes(at: locations)

            if node[0].name == "NewGameButton" {

                let gameScene = SKScene(fileNamed: "GameScene")
                gameScene!.size = self.size
                gameScene!.scaleMode = .aspectFit

                let transition = SKTransition.flipHorizontal(withDuration: 1)
                view!.presentScene(gameScene!, transition: transition)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: please provide code instead of image or screenshot.

Comment: thank you for the answer , i added it on the top :)

Comment: Hey there! Could you try removing the `gameScene!.size = self.size` line and changing `gameScene!.scaleMode` to .aspectFill?

Comment: thank you so much it works !! <3